# A Gaussian elimination for computing the signature?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a problem for a qualification exam I am preparing. Consider the bilnear form $\langle A, B \rangle := \text{tr}(A^{T}JB)$ where $J = I_{2 \times 2}^{T}$ on the space of $2 \times 3$ real matrices. The problem is to compute the signature of this form. The answer to this problem is $(3, 3)$.

With the standard basis, we have $\begin{bmatrix}0 & I_{3\times3} \\ I_{3\times3} & 0\end{bmatrix}$, so I am assuming that there is some ways that we can swap the rows with adding minus signs to compute the signature. Is there such one? Then how does it affect the standard basis? I would appreciate it if the answer is given by a computation on this particular example or another bilinear form explicitly, not the explanation of the theory.

There is an algorithm to find an "orthogonal" basis for a symmetric bilinear form, but I think it takes too long!

Comment: If you're just computing the signature, then it suffices to find the eigenvalues of the matrix and note their sign.

Comment: It helps to note that
$$
\pmatrix{
0 & I_{3\times3} \\ I_{3\times3} & 0
} = 
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} \otimes I_{3 \times 3}
$$
if you're familiar with the Kronecker product.

Comment: Ha, it's that simple? But I think you are right...

Comment: Yep! It's that simple.

Comment: Thanks. I was desperate because it was difficult to find explicit computations from books.